# native-base Accordion Error with indexOf is not a function

Tags: react-native, runtime-error, native-base

I am new to React Native, so I apologize if this is a stupid question, but I am getting an error using the Accordion component from native-base.  I gives me a message of "e.state.selected.indexOf is not a function".

I have the example code from the native-base docs pasted into a snack [here](https://snack.expo.io/@gjeff/nativebase-accordion) to show the problem. Here is that code, it is pretty simple:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Container, Header, Content, Accordion, Text } from "native-base";

const dataArray = [
  { title: "First Element", content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" },
  { title: "Second Element", content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" },
  { title: "Third Element", content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" }
];

export default class AccordionExample extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Header />
        <Content padder>
          <Accordion dataArray={dataArray} expanded={0}/>
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

The native-base package specified in the `package.json` is `*`, which fetches the latest stable version 2.15.2. This release seems to have a bug that requires you to pass expanded as an array.

You can find the discussion about this issue [here](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/3364).

Using the following syntax should fix the issue:

```html
<Accordion dataArray={dataArray} expanded={[0]}/>
```

Alternatively, you could downgrade the version manually by setting an older version in the `package.json` file.

Comment: Holy cow, you deserve way more upvotes for this. Thank you so much!